# Rabbitmq can't manage after a time

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq queue that each data which publish to this queue is approximately 1 MB size. Every second 4 or 5 data publish to this queue.

Consumer consume each data one by one(Fetch=1). When i stop the consumer service 30000 queued message became ready to consume. When i start the consumer its consume rate 30/s+. It is just fine for now.

Hovewer in day light publisher never stops publishing and consumer can handle the queue. But at night publisher don't send data anymore(it is not error. It is how it suppose to be). At the first light of the next day publisher starts to publish 7 data per second. This time rabbit queue is started to go up continuesly.

First thought was that consumer can't handle the data. But it can consume 30/s+ data every sec.

I know that consume speed depends on consumer.

BUT.

I think that rabbit have some mechanism that after a time it decrease the consumer speed. Maybe it is lock mechanism maybe internal logs. I couldn't find any solution. Please help

[image: This is what i mean]

This picture shows the limit of consumer speed.

[image]

Comment: How is the consumer implemented? Does it use a push or a pull approach? It only consumes 3.8 messages per second. *Edit:* The screenshot  shows a *Consumer utilisation* of 0%. This means that RabbitMQ always has to wait for the consumer to be able to handle the next message. RabbitMQ can never just push a published message to the consumer. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/

Comment: It uses basic.consume function. It is pull approach(rigth?). The fetch data variable is not defined(it is 1 as i know by default). The problem is that consumer can consume 30/s+ data every sec.

The queue is working for 24 hours. For 8 hour publisher never stopped publishing. for 11 hour publisher didn't send any data. At he morning publisher started with 7 data/s.

I ll try to capture the 30/s+ consume speed and send again.

Comment: How do you know the consumer handles 30 messages per second? Is it able to handle this rate now?

Comment: It is very confusing. When data(30000 queue) is ready, consumer consume 30/s. When publisher is not idle rabbit just go fine. But publisher goes idle for a time(10h for me) and start flow after idle time consume speed. I ll test again and send 30/s speed screenshot. I didn't check consumer utilization before.

Comment: I never increase the prefetch count. I ll try again. Thanks for the answer @LutzHorn. The blog explain most thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lutz Horn

> How is the consumer implemented? Does it use a push or a pull approach? It only consumes 3.8 messages per second. Edit: The screenshot shows a Consumer utilisation of 0%. This means that RabbitMQ always has to wait for the consumer to be able to handle the next message. RabbitMQ can never just push a published message to the consumer. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/– Lutz Horn